# Start Cypress tests from DevOps

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, cypress

I'm trying to set up Cypress to run automated tests directly from DevOps using a pipeline. It looks like it's already partially communicating to me, but I don't know why I'm getting the following error there:

[image]

I call `. \\phasp13jm29\UICypress\cypress open`:

There is such a structure in this directory.

[image]

The package.json file contains:

[image]

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Could you share more details about the test execution or some code please? Otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I added some information to the topic. I hope it will serve better for orientation and possible help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are calling cypress in tfs agent (test runner) from a remote machine (`\\phasp13jm29`) which potentially a mis-usage. In a nutshell, cypress is nodejs package. By that said, you need to install nodejs and cypress in tfs agent. You may want to check out [cypress system requirements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#System-requirements) for further details.

To fulfill the pipeline, you also need to make sure cypress test scripts are available in tfs agent (by copying them over network or git checkout or your own way).

The last step is to kick of the test execution by calling `npx cypress run` [with appropriate flags and/or configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#How-to-run-commands) or `npm run test` (from your package.json).

Just my 2 cents and I hope it's somewhat helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I need to add nodejs installation to these steps like in picture ?

Comment: Technically, you need nodejs and cypress installed in tfs agent (test runner). In other words, you need to make sure you can run cypress tests in the tfs agent manually beforehand.